# Laravel 5 and Socialite

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I have installed `laravel/socialite` in my project but I can't understand how to make it work...

I have this in my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "~2.0"
    },
```

I have added in my config/app.php:

```
    'Socialize' => 'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider'
```

and:

```
    'Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider',
```

Then:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Added a new route:

```
Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@getFacebookLogin');
```

Add the new method:

```
/**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFacebookLogin()
    {
        return \Socialize::with('facebook')->redirect();
    }
```

But all I get is:

```
FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 43: Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::with()
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
'Socialize' => 'Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite'
```

as an alias in your app.php.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Facade alias doesn't really work anymore for Socialite. I think the docs could use some love, in general, too (especially since I don't think it's supposed to be aliased as "socialize").

What I found to work was to alter your `use` statement to

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory as Socialite;
```

and drop the alias entry altogether.